# Command npm run build error

Tags: npm, swagger

I've downloaded the swagger-js zip from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js, and I have modified some file, so I need to rebuild it. The command npm install works correctly, but when I run the command npm run build it fail and return me some errors, this is the content of the npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok  
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',  
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',  
1 verbose cli   'run',  
1 verbose cli   'build' ]  
2 info using npm@3.10.10  
3 info using node@v6.10.3  
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]  
5 info lifecycle swagger-client@3.0.11~prebuild: swagger-client@3.0.11  
6 silly lifecycle swagger-client@3.0.11~prebuild: no script for prebuild, continuing  
7 info lifecycle swagger-client@3.0.11~build: swagger-client@3.0.11  
8 verbose lifecycle swagger-client@3.0.11~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true  
9 verbose lifecycle swagger-client@3.0.11~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Sibo\Desktop\swagger-ui\swagger-js-master\swagger-js-master\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python27;C:\PCI Geomatics\Geomatica 2017\exe;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Sibo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Sibo\AppData\Roaming\npm  
10 verbose lifecycle swagger-client@3.0.11~build: CWD: C:\Users\Sibo\Desktop\swagger-ui\swagger-js-master\swagger-js-master  
11 silly lifecycle swagger-client@3.0.11~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
11 silly lifecycle   'NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.js' ]  
12 silly lifecycle swagger-client@3.0.11~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null  
13 info lifecycle swagger-client@3.0.11~build: Failed to exec build script  
14 verbose stack Error: swagger-client@3.0.11 build: `NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.js`  
14 verbose stack Exit status 1  
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)  
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)  
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)  
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)  
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)  
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)  
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)  
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)  
15 verbose pkgid swagger-client@3.0.11  
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\Sibo\Desktop\swagger-ui\swagger-js-master\swagger-js-master  
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393  
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"  
19 error node v6.10.3  
20 error npm  v3.10.10  
21 error code ELIFECYCLE  
22 error swagger-client@3.0.11 build: `NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.js`  
22 error Exit status 1  
23 error Failed at the swagger-client@3.0.11 build script 'NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.js'.  
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.  
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the swagger-client package,  
23 error not with npm itself.  
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:  
23 error     NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.js 
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:  
23 error     npm bugs swagger-client  
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:  
23 error     npm owner ls swagger-client  
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.  
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm using windows 10
nodejs version: 6.10.3
npm versione: 3.10.10